# Expoを入れてReactNativeの環境構築をしたいがPATHが通らない

Tags: react-native, zsh

**やりたいこと**
expoをインストールしてReactNativeの開発環境をつくりたいです。

**困っていること**

以下の記事を参考にして環境構築をしていますが、`zsh: command not found: expo` と出てしまいます。

[ExpoではじめるReact Native開発環境の構築 - CodeZine](https://codezine.jp/article/detail/11384?p=3)

`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.5.0/bin/:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc` をやってみましたが、

```
export $PATH
export: not valid in this context: /Users/harukaashiuchi/.yarn/bin:/Users/harukaashiuchi/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
```

と出てしまいます。PATHの設定がよくわかっておらずどう直せばいいのかわかりません。

zshrcファイルは以下です。

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.5.0/bin/:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.5.0/bin/:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.5.0/bin/:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.5.0/bin/:$PATH"
```

環境
node v14.15.3

ご回答よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.zshrc` を見る限り PATH の設定は追記されているようなので、コマンドを実行しているターミナルをいったん開き直すか、`source ~/.zshrc` で .zshrc を読み直してみてください。
(恐らく繰り返し実行したために重複する行があるようなので、必要に応じて Vim などのエディタで整理しておきましょう)

---

なお、下記のエラーは `export` コマンドの実行方法が間違っているためです。

> ```
> export $PATH
> export: not valid in this context: > /Users/harukaashiuchi/.yarn/bin:/Users/harukaashiuchi/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:...
> ```

正しい構文は以下の通りです。

```
export 環境変数名="設定する値"
```

具体的には、.zshrc にも追記したようなコマンドをそのまま実行します。

```
export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.5.0/bin/:$PATH"
```